Is it true that full sin of wife is absorbed by the husband, and half virtue of the husband is transfered to the wife?
Is is true that

half of husband's virtue (Punya) is transferred to the wife.

All of wife's sin is absorbed by the husband.


Does the virtue of wife also get transferred to the husband ?
How true is this ?
What part of Punya and Paap is shared between husband and wife.
Please tell in details.

Related1 Related2 Related3 Related4
